# convert this php code to javascript - strpos, str_replace, substr

Tags: php, javascript

I have a piece of code written in PHP inside my javascript tag. I figured it would be better to have all javascript inside my script tag.

So I would need help to convert these 3 lines of code in javascript:

```
if (strpos($video['thumbs']['master'], '/thumbs_old/') !== false) {
    $position = strpos($video['thumbs']['master'], '.flv');
    $oldFlipBookThumb = str_replace(substr($video['thumbs']['master'], $position), '.flv', $video['thumbs']['master']);
 }
```

Comment: How do the corresponding JavaScript variables look like...? Hints: [`<String>.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), [`<String>.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [`<String>.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Comment: These methods already exist in JavaScript: [`String.indexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53xtt423(v=vs.94).aspx), [`String.replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0kbytzc(v=vs.94).aspx), [`String.substr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0esxc5wy(v=vs.94).aspx). Did you have problems using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `search()` method of the string object - it returns the position of the match, or -1 if no match is found

```
var position = -1, oldFlipBookThumb;
var str = '<?php echo $video['thumbs']['master'];?>';
if(str.search("/thumbs_old/" != -1){
    position = str.search(".flv");
}
if(position != -1){
    oldFlipBookThumb = str.replace(str.substring(position, Number(position) + 4), '.flv');
}
```

I could be mistaken, but it looks to me like you are replacing the string ".flv" with the string ".flv".

In any case, the `substring()` method of the string object extracts the characters in a string between "from" and "to", not including "to" itself. `string.substring(from, to)`

the `replace()` method of the string object searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring. `string.replace(regexp/substr,newstring)`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [php.js](http://phpjs.org/), which has specific direct ports of PHP functions for JavaScript.

EDIT: As commenter(s) have rightly pointed out, php.js is not without its flaws (bloat, bugs) so by far the best solution would be to take what you need from there, or use what JS already offers and tailor it.

Comment: Some of them are buggy though.

Comment: While the php.js project is cool, it's largely bloat since many of the same methods already exist within JavaScript itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for javascript, I didn't test it but maybe could help:

```
function strpos (haystack, needle, offset) {
  var i = (haystack).indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}

//call the function as:
var res='scripts,tutorials,tools';
strpos(res, ',');

//result will be: 2
```

For replace:

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace("old", "dont want");
document.write(new_text);
```